# Conditional filter retrieve partial object

Tags: c#, mongodb

how to retrieve partial object?

```java
  {
    Id:123,
    Name:"david",
    Languages:[{b:"en"},{b:"ru"}]
  }
```

```cs
        public async Task<myObj> Get(long id, string lang=null)
            {
                FilterDefinition<myObj> filter = Builders<myObj>.Filter.Eq(s => s.Id, id) 
                                                   & Builders<myObj>.Filter.ElemMatch(l => l.Languages, s => s.b== lang);

                ProjectionDefinition<myObj> projection = Builders<Symptom>.Projection
                                          .Include(d => d.Id)
                                          .Include(d => d.Name)
                                          .Include(d => d.Languages[-1]);

                FindOptions<myObj> options = new FindOptions<myObj> { Projection = projection };
                using (IAsyncCursor<myObj> cursor = await db.Collection.FindAsync(filter, options))
                {
                    return cursor.SingleOrDefault();
                }
            }
```

if i call function get(123,"cn") i expect to get:

```java
       {
            Id:123,
            Name:"david",
            Languages:null
       }
```

instead of null.

how to fix the query to achieve my demand?

Comment: In your example, what's cn? Do you need the output limited to what you want to display for display purpose only?

Answer (score 0):

i think this will get the job done:

```cs
public async Task<myObj> Get(long id, string lang = null)
{
    var res = await db.Collection.AsQueryable()
                                 .Where(m =>
                                        m.Id == id &&
                                        m.Languages.Any(l => l.b == lang))
                                 .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    return res ?? new myObj { _Id = id, Languages = null };
}
```

Comment: Id is just one filed for the example, i have more fields that i need from db

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the languages only when they match (and null if none match up), then try the following

```
public async Task<myObj> Get(long id, string lang = null)
{
    FilterDefinition<myObj> filter = Builders<myObj>.Filter.Eq(s => s.Id, id) 
    var result = await collection.Find(filter).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    if (result != null)
        result.Languages = result.Languages?.Where(lng => lng.b.Equals(lang)).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

You will get your object that you want based on the ID.. then further it will return only those languages that match up with language that you are passing (null or otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

It's working. I don't know what you mean by "instead of null".

One minor thing, that you would like to *not* include `Languges`, instead you projected the `Languages` to an array range with the `[-1]`. So it's just return last element of the array. The final code is:

> > db.ItemWithLanguages.find()
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("5dfb57c9692d22eefa6e0cfe"), "Id" : 123, "Name" : "david", "Languages" : [ { "B" : "en" }, { "B" : "cn" } ] }

```
internal class MyObj
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [BsonId]
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    public ObjectId MyId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Language> Languages { get; set; }
}

internal class Language
{
    public string B { get; set; }
}

public static async Task<MyObj> Get(IMongoCollection<MyObj> collection, long id, string lang = null)
{
    FilterDefinition<MyObj> filter = Builders<MyObj>.Filter.Eq(s => s.Id, id)
                                     & Builders<MyObj>.Filter.ElemMatch(l => l.Languages, s => s.B == lang);

    // excluding d.Languages by not including it.
    // it makes Languages = null.
    ProjectionDefinition<MyObj> projection = Builders<MyObj>.Projection
        .Include(d => d.Id)
        .Include(d => d.Name);

    FindOptions<MyObj> options = new FindOptions<MyObj> { Projection = projection };
    using (IAsyncCursor<MyObj> cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter, options))
    {
        return cursor.SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

...

```
string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
var myObjs = db.GetCollection<MyObj>("ItemWithLanguages");
MyObj ret;
Task.Run(async () => { ret = await Get(myObjs, 123, "cn"); }).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter()
    .GetResult();
```